# Closing php connections to mysql automatically

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have too many connections to mysql within my php script.
The connections are not closing - I may have forgot to close the in some places in my code.

Is there any way to define the sql to close all my php connections to the server automatically at the end of the script?

Comment: try this, $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class to manay mysql connection like this

```
class MysqlConnection
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

}
```

When the script run to the end, php will destroy all objects, then call the destructor automatically. So the connection can be closed also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using persistent connections then PHP automatically closes all connections to MySQL when the script ends.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

> Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically destroyed when a PHP script finishes its execution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I was not using persistent connections so the connection was supposed to close wheb the script ends.

However, I was using a third-party code named "prototype.js".
I don't know why but it was blocking my code from closing the php connections.
After I removed the following line everything worked fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js"></script>
```